# How can I do a dashed line of mean for each bar plot and change scale of axis, python

Tags: python, mean

I have a bar plot, but I have two problems. First, in the y-axis I have values like 3500,3000,... How can change the values of the y-axis for something like $3.5\times 10^{3}$, $3\times 10^{3}$,.. obviously in this example, I could change the scale, but the idea is that it be more general and faster.

And second, how can I do a dashed line with the mean for **each bar**?
(I do not explain well, my idea is to form a curve with the means of each bar)

```
 import matplotlib
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import numpy as np

 men_means = [2000, 3400, 3000, 3005, 2700]
 women_means = [2500, 3200, 3004, 2000, 2005]

 x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations
 width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

 fig, ax = plt.subplots()
 rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, men_means, width, label='Men')
 rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, women_means, width, label='Women')
```

[Bar Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2Zm0.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
plt.axvline(mean, color="red")
```

for draw a line in x axis (v in the function name means vertical), where the mean is your mean value!
Or

```
plt.axhline(mean, color="red")
```

for draw a line in y axis (h in the function name means horizontal).

[Here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline.html) you can find all possible options for axvline() function.

For change the scale you can try with:

```
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

[Here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/pyplots/pyplot_scales.html) you can find all type of scale supported, like linear scale, log scale, symmetrical log scale, logit scale and some examples.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I do not explain well, my idea is to form a curve with the means of each bar. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the axis you want by changing the scale:

```py
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

Answer (score 0):

For the dashed lines, add this to your code:

```
ax.axhline(np.mean(men_means), linestyle='--', label='Men mean', color='blue')
ax.axhline(np.mean(women_means), linestyle='--', label='Women mean', color='orange')
ax.legend()
```

(I've chosen labels/colours arbitrarily)

For your y-axis, if you want scientific notation you could try this:

```
ax.ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='sci', scilimits=(0,0))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I do not explain well, my idea is to form a curve with the means of each bar..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, what are the datapoints that you want to plot?